# Как в urls передать число с символом тире

Tags: django

Есть url:

`re_path(r'^editfacil/(?P<facility_id>\d+)/$', mainapp.editfacility2, name='editfacility2'),`

При передаче, например, editfacil/4 дальнейшая функция отрабатывает, но если указать, например editfacil/-4 то происходит ошибка.

Нужно как-то в регулярном выражении указать знак -

Comment: Я бы начал с вопроса, что нужно курить что бы сделать отрицательные `id`?

Comment: Но добавить опциональный дефис можно так `(?P<facility_id>-?\d+)`

Comment: @AlexeyTen https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1 